# An easy way to send data in datagrid to an email address?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I want to send the data in my datagrid to an email so I put the name of the datagrid in the mail body area but it is showing me that it cannot convert it to string data.

This is my code - please help me:

```
private void emailgrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("to_address");
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
        mail.Body = DataGrid;

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get an error and what is the output ?

Comment: its is not sending the data in the datagrid

Comment: so there is no error with the above code, correct ?
where is your code for smtp

Comment: why are you redeclaring mailBody again after it has been set the value? It should throw you a compile time error

Comment: i dont have a code for smtp

Comment: `var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "*****");

        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@domain.com");
        mail.To.Add("yourmail@domain.com");
        mail.Subject = "Subject;
        mail.Body = "Body";
        client.Send(mail);`

Comment: what is the mail object that you have in your code above

Comment: @SMARTG., I see your edit, is it able to send mail now  ?

Comment: it is not still working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply "send the `DataGrid` in an email" as you are attempting to do. Emails show text, and sometimes pictures- not full WPF controls. The reason you are gettign an error is because `MailMessage.Body` is a `string` property, and there's no built-in conversion between `string` and `DataGrid`.

What you need to do is convert the contents of the `DataGrid` into a format that is presentable in an email.

If you set `MailMessage.IsBodyHtml` to `true`, then you can put HTML content into the `Body` property. This allows you to use HTML elements like [`table`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), which would let you properly display your `DataGrid`'s contents correctly. You should be able to find enough information online to build an HTML table out of your data, or maybe even find someone else who has posted code that already does this.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer to the question

```
private void emailgrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        //put your SMTP address and port here.
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("");
        //Put the email address
        mail.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
        //Put the email where you want to send.
        mail.To.Add("email@gmail.com");

        mail.Subject = "suubject";

        StringBuilder sbBody = new StringBuilder();

        sbBody.AppendLine("body");

        mail.Body = sbBody.ToString();

        //Your log file path
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"C:\XML\see.xml");

        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        //Your username and password!
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
        //Set Smtp Server port
        SmtpServer.Port = 25;
        //SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("Hello User Your Mail Has Been Sent");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

}
```